# Supernova.io Hooks

Tags: hook, figma, supernova

How often is there a check on changes to the source data for the hook to trigger?

We've only managed to get it to trigger automatically / instantly once.

We've tried deleting and reconnecting the source, trying different sources and making new projects.

Sometimes, it just doesn't trigger at all.

Anything that might shed light would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The frequency of source data check in Supernova Hooks varies.*

But if you're having trouble with the hook triggering once or not at all, here's what you can check:

1. Double-check that the hook is set up and configured to trigger based
   on the changes you want to see.
2. Make sure there aren't any network/firewall blocks preventing the
   hook from triggering.
3. Check if the source data is being updated correctly and if those
   changes are reflected in the hook.
4. If all else fails, hit up the Supernova support team for help.

And, don't forget, the issue might be with Figma, not Supernova. So, check their docs and support as well.